# Regular expression for at least one character and one number in a 5-30 length text

Tags: regex

Requirements:

• Usernames should be between 5 and 30 characters long
• They must contain letters and numbers.
• Usernames are not case sensitive.
• Spaces must not be used.

Allow: "!,@,#,$,%,^,?,_,~,-"

I've tried something like this for the length and normal characters requirements.

```
^[a-z0-9_-]{5,30}$
```

This does not guarantee I get both letters and numbers - only that they are allowed

```
[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]
```

I don't know how to limit this to 5-30 characters total?

Comment: So how do you plan to use this regular expression? What are the details of the implementation - you want a "pass/fail" of some kind presumably? I am not sure why "usernames are not case sensitive" matters - are you saying "they must contain letters and numbers, but the case of the letters doesn't matter"?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-for-alpanumeric-with-at-least-1-number-and-1-character/7684859#7684859 for inspiration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[\w@#$%^?~-]{5,30}$
```

#### Live Demo & Examples: http://www.rubular.com/r/EXHHCoq0WC

**Explanation:**

- `^` is line start
- `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` is a positive lookahead that will make sure there is atleast one alphabet
- `(?=.*?[0-9])` is a positive lookahead that will make sure there is atleast one digit
- `[\w@#$%^?~-]{5,30}` is using character class for 5 to 30 characters specified inside square brackets
- `$` is line end

#### Lookaround Reference: [www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: It is a good answer. Given the OPs inexperience, an explanation might be warranted.

Comment: @Floris: Thanks, Yes I am typing some explanation.

Comment: Very professional of you to take the time and help me seeing I didn't have the time for posting more information about my question. This works great, hope this help someone else.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

`[:alpha:]` is a "special character" that is "any upper or lower case letter"

`[:digit:]` is "any digit"

`[!@#$%^?_~-]` means "match any of these characters"

`[^ ]`  means "don't match a space"

`{5,30}`   means "match the preceding expression between 5 and 30 times

Regex allows for things like `|` between two expressions to match "either this or that".

http://rubular.com/  is a great "regex sandbox" - you can enter expressions, and see what matches

When you have played around with the above for a while and got it "almost working", there will be people here to help you "get across the finish line".

Comment: this is great information, I'll definitely to look into it. Thanks for the advice as well, I did research a lot but I didn't have the time to show you guys my whole investigation, I'll make sure to fill my questions with more information. Have a good day.

Comment: Better questions get better answers. You are getting some very experienced brain power for free - you show respect by making the best question you can... It is a learning journey for all of us. I made a couple of small edits to your question to show simple ways to improve it.