# regex for alphanumeric only is not working

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, validation

This is the code I am trying:

```
string MatchNumberPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

if (!Regex.IsMatch(cueTextBox9.Text, MatchNumberPattern))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter 8 Space Alphanumeric BT ID only");
    cueTextBox9.Text = String.Empty;
}
else
{
    do something();
}
```

It's accepting `aaaaaaaa`, but I want a combination of both alpha and numbers like `aaaa1234`.

Comment: Of course it's taking `aaaaaaaa`, you specified it to take anything that is a-z or A-Z or 0-9 any number of times. So it would take `aaabbbjfgkgAJFFJL0142342` as well. What would you like to do? If you only want to match numbers: `^[0-9]*$` or `^[0-9]+$` if empty string is not ok. Instead of `[0-9]` you can use `\d` as a short-hand, but first please clarify what you want :)

Comment: i want to accept only alphanumeric ,not alpha only or not numbers only..

Comment: Alphanumeric means "Alphanumeric is a combination of alphabetic and numeric characters..." (quote from wiki), so it means letters and digits. This is what you're already doing here.

Comment: dude, i am saying i want both alpha and numerics in it... both in one string then it will be acceptable.otherwise not

Comment: Use `@"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`. Is that what you need?

Comment: thanks man. it worked. :) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: For future reference: "I would like my regular expression to only match inputs which contain both letters and digits at the same time". And don't "dude" me.

Comment: that what alphanumeric only means. by the way thanks for the advice :) @SzabolcsDézsi

Comment: I am reopening this question since  the answer in the [Regex for alphanumeric with at least 1 number and 1 character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-for-alphanumeric-with-at-least-1-number-and-1-character) is a trash "why-not-use-this" answer without any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To require both a letter and a digit to appear in the input, you need *positive lookaheads*:

```
@"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ7lK2/1)

The `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` makes sure there is a letter and `(?=.*[0-9])` makes sure there is a digit in the input string.

Since you are taking the input from a single-line text box, it is safe to use `.` in the lookahead. As an alternative, you can use `@"^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"` (based on the principle of contrast).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for a digit and match an alpha before the rest.

```
^(?i)(?=\D*\d)\d*[A-Z][A-Z\d]*$
```

- `^` start of string
- `(?i)` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for caseless matching
- `(?=\D*\d)` loook ahead for `\D*` any amount of *non-digits* followed by `\d` digit
- if succeeds match `\d*[A-Z]` any amount of digits followed by alpha
- `[A-Z\d]*` match any amount of alphanumeric characters until
- `$` end of string

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zG9cD8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
  async Task<string> CheckPasswordAgainstPasswordSettings(string password)
        {
            Regex rxUpper= new Regex(@"[A-Z]");
            Regex rxLower = new Regex(@"[a-z]");



            var passwordcomplexityrulesetttings=  (await _PasswordComplexityRuleService.All()).First();
          if(passwordcomplexityrulesetttings==null)
            {
                return "password valid";
            }
          if(passwordcomplexityrulesetttings.MinLength> password.Length)
            {
                return "password is not of minimum length";

            }
            if (passwordcomplexityrulesetttings.MustContainLettersNumbers)
            {
                if(password.Any(a=>!char.IsDigit(a)&&!char.IsLetter(a)) && !passwordcomplexityrulesetttings.MustContainSpecialCharacters)
                
                {
                    return "password must contain letters and numbers";
                }


            }

            if (passwordcomplexityrulesetttings.MustContainSpecialCharacters)
            {

                if (!password.Any(a => !char.IsDigit(a) && !char.IsLetter(a)))

                {
                    return "password must contain special characters";
                }


            }
            if (passwordcomplexityrulesetttings.MustContainUpperLower)
            {

                if (!rxLower.Match(password).Success||!rxUpper.Match(password).Success)

                {
                    return "password must contain upper and lower case";
                }


            }
            
            return "password valid";

        }
```