# regex for only alphanumeric without underscores

Tags: python, regex

I had a text string as following:

```
text = "907525191737280e , hjjhkj789jkh 2554nagy289 2 8 2 2 7 5 2 working welcome , a dp83640as25 , dp83867 e2 e25"
```

I tried using the following regex expression(from:[regex for alphanumeric only is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380322/regex-for-alphanumeric-only-is-not-working)) to identify the alphanumeric words only.

and changed it as following: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*` But i didn't get the result that i wanted and I also tried `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` but did it also got failed.

Desired output:

```
907525191737280e hjjhkj789jkh 2554nagy289 dp83640as25 dp83867 e2 e25
```

I am new to regex and trying to learn it. could you please help what am I missing?

Comment: Why is the simple `2` rejected? In my book that is alphanumeric...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to check for a digit using a lookahead and match at least a single char a-zA-Z.

You don't need the anchor `^` because that asserts the start of the string. You might use a word bounary `\b` to make sure the match is not part of a larger word.

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])` Positive lookahead, assert a digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` Match a char a-zA-Z between all allowed chars
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/50Q49g/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need all words which contain at least one numeric character and at least one alpha character, this might be done with using `import string` rather than `import re` following way:

```
import string
text = "907525191737280e , hjjhkj789jkh 2554nagy289 2 8 2 2 7 5 2 working welcome , a dp83640as25 , dp83867 e2 e25"
words = text.split()
anwords = [w for w in words if set(w).intersection(string.ascii_letters) and set(w).intersection(string.digits)]
print(anwords)  # ['907525191737280e', 'hjjhkj789jkh', '2554nagy289', 'dp83640as25', 'dp83867', 'e2', 'e25']
```

Note that this solution, similar to pattern you recognizes only ASCII letters as alphabetic. Remember that `re` is useful module, but some tasks are easier to get done another way.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying - no regex needed, really:

```
text = "907525191737280e , hjjhkj789jkh 2554nagy289 2 8 2 2 7 5 2 working welcome , a dp83640as25 , dp83867 e2 e25"

alnums = [word
          for word in text.split()
          if word.isalnum()]

print(alnums)
```

This yields

```
['907525191737280e', 'hjjhkj789jkh', '2554nagy289', '2', '8', '2', '2', '7', '5', '2', 'working', 'welcome', 'a', 'dp83640as25', 'dp83867', 'e2', 'e25']
```

---

Add other conditions if needed (e.g. the length):

```
alnums = [word
          for word in text.split()
          if word.isalnum() and len(word) > 1]
```

Which would yield

```
['907525191737280e', 'hjjhkj789jkh', '2554nagy289', 'working', 'welcome', 'dp83640as25', 'dp83867', 'e2', 'e25']
```