# Textbox to accept charcters & numbers or Alphabets but not ONLY numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a javascript validation on a textbox which can accept.

**a. Characters

  b. Characters with Numbers**

> It should not accept only numbers

For example i want something like:-

**Abc123**, **A7 organisation**.

but I dont want like;-

**333333** , **2222222**.

*Also, special characters are also not allowed*

I tried like below js function but it is not working

```
function NumersWithCharValidation() {
    var textBoxvalue = document.getElementById('txtNameOfFirm').value;
    alert(textBoxvalue);
    if (textBoxvalue.match("/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/")) {
        alert('Good to go');
    }
    else {
        alert('Only Numbers are not allowed');
    } 
}

<input id="txtNameOfFirm" runat="server" onkeypress="return NumersWithCharValidation();" maxlength="200" type="text" width="65%" />
```

kindly suggest what is wrong

Comment: check if only numbers are present `/^\d*$/` and if so reject the input

Comment: Try using only one of these 2 characters _"_ and _/_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for alphanumeric with at least 1 number and 1 character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-for-alphanumeric-with-at-least-1-number-and-1-character)

Comment: @antoniskamamis: i tried with ur regex, but even after putting alphabets its going in else part

Comment: @coder you have to reverse your if else conditions `if (textBoxvalue.match(/^\d*$/)) { alert('only numbers abort'); } else { alert('good to go'); }` also regex in match does not need quotes

Comment: Your regex is fine, just remove the quotes around it.

Comment: @georg: aah, yeah let me try and check with that too

Comment: @georg: Nope, its  not working with that regex

Comment: @coder: it does work: https://regex101.com/r/sI5jJ6/1

Comment: @georg: after space when i put numbers it is not giving me error. Like `121212 12121` why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the method to

```
function NumersWithCharValidation(thisObj) {
    var textBoxvalue = thisObj.value;
    if ( textBoxvalue.length > 0 && isNaN( textBoxvalue ) && !textBoxvalue.match( /\W/ ) ) 
    {
        alert('Good to go');
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('Only Numbers are not allowed. Special characters are also not allowed' );
    } 
}

<input id="txtNameOfFirm" runat="server" onkeypress="return NumersWithCharValidation(this);" maxlength="200" type="text" width="65%" />
```

`isNaN( "textBoxvalue" )` will check if the value is a pure number

`textBoxvalue.match( /\W/ )` checks if there is any special character in the value

Comment: @gurvinder372 you have to remove the quotes from the check in isNaN

Comment: @coder there is a regex `/\W/` is a regex that matches non-alpha-numeric characters. Did you try the code?

Comment: @gurvinder372: yes i tried it. it seems its working for me. but one thing i want to ask, it repeatedly gives me alert even when there is no text entered into the textbox. why ?

Comment: @coder added the condition to check for empty string as well.

Comment: @gurvinder372: No, that is not what I want. See. when I go to add alphabet for the first time in the textbox, it straight away go into the else part and gives error as`alert('Only Numbers are not allowed. Special characters are also not allowed');` why ? does it is related to `onkeypress` thing ??

Comment: @coder `it is related to onkeypress thing` yes, if you don't want to be bothered with every keypress then use **onblur** so that only when you tab out of the input box the validation will be done

Comment: superb. working fine..Accepting the answer :) Thanks a lot

Comment: hi @gurvinder372: are you their?? just one small doubt

Comment: i am still getting the _else part error_, when I just keep mouse and take out the mouse without inserting any text on **onblur** why ?

Comment: @coder in that case don't put `textBoxvalue.length > 0 &&` in the if condition since that is what giving this condition

Comment: should I remove and check ??

Comment: @coder yes, please do it and let me know if problem still persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103482/discussion-between-coder-and-gurvinder372).

Comment: yes problem is still their, can u come on chat so that I can explain u in detail

Comment: @gurvinder372: hi, are you their ? just need one small change here in the regex.

Comment: after space when i put numbers it is not giving me error. Like `121212 12121` why ??

Comment: any help @gurvinder372 ??

Comment: @coder gimme some time, can you share a fiddle in the meantime?

Comment: sure, waiting for ur answer. i guess you understand the logic ??. yeah i will share the fiddle in 2mins

Comment: @coder you made a simple error, you need to chose 'Wrap in head' rather than `onload` setting in jsfiddle.

Comment: @gurvinder372: ok, i just added the code and gave u. kindly help what is wrong

Comment: @gurvinder372: it is still taking `23432 423423` like this, which it should not

Comment: @coder but `23432 423423` satisfies the critieria you have mentioned in your OP.

Comment: @gurvinder372: no, i dont  want only numbers. have a look at the question. I want `abc3 test` but not `1212 3434`

Comment: @gurvinder372: when I add text like `abc test test` it stilll gives me error, WHY ??

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex like this? Positive lookahead for letters, it works for your example inputs.

`if (textBoxvalue.match("/^(?=[a-zA-Z]+)[\w\s,]*$/")) {
    alert('Good to go');
 } else {
    alert('Only Numbers are not allowed');
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This will not allow the user to type any further

```
jQuery("#txtNameOfFirm").keypress(function (event, ui)
{ return NumersWithCharValidation(event) });
```

and

```
function NumersWithCharValidation(evt) {

    if (jQuery("#txtNameOfFirm").val().match(/^[0-9]+$/) == null)
    { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```