# Check if username contains numbers and letters in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to check if username contains both letters and numbers.I was trying to use `alpha_num`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required',   
    'username' => 'required|alpha_num',
    'password' => 'min:6|required',
    ]);
}
```

But it didn't work.
Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: Do you need the username to follow a certain pattern? Or just check if it contains letters and numbers?

Comment: I want just check if it contains at least one letter & one number.Like John123,Not john or 123.

Comment: Combine the custom validation referred to by Crozet with the regex in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7684859/1483117

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What is it doing that constitutes a non-working state?

Answer (score 0):

The alpha_num filter just checks if the username contains only letters and numbers but not if both are present.

Depending on your need, there are two regex that can validate the username

### If you want (at least) one letter and one number and whatever else

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $myString) && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Contains at least one letter and one number';
}
```

- `1a]-/*+` and `aaaaaaaa1` will pass this test
- `1-_%` and `a` will not pass the test

### If you want (at least) one letter and one number but only letters and numbers

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Contains at least one letter and one number and only alphanum';
}
```

*more info about this regex : https://regex101.com/r/GrLGbT/1*

- `1111111a` and `aaaaaaaa1` will pass this test
- `1a-` and `a` will not pass the test

---

Once you have your regex, you will need to create a custom validator. Have a look here for the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

if you want input not to be numeric you can try
 'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s-]+$/u|max:255',

if you want it to be  alpha numeric then:
'name' => 'required|string|max:255',