# RegEx to extract alphanumeric+symbol combinations from a string

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that can extract different types of string+number+symbol combinations out of a string. The types of strings I am trying to extract are:

```
avs-tldr-02
cc+asede
x86_64
```

The types of edge cases I am testing are these string appearing at the beginning, middle and end of sentences:

```
avs-tldr-02 this is a test
cc+asede this is a test
x86_64 this is a test

this is a test avs-tldr-02 this is a test
this is a test cc+asede this is a test
this is a test x86_64 this is a test

this is a test avs-tldr-02
this is a test cc+asede
this is a test x86_64
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684859/1312137) excellent answer, I have dabbled around with "lookaround" assertions in RegEx and have come up with the following:

```
(?=.*[:alnum:])(?=.*[:punct:])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

However, this keeps matching the first word of the string - I understand why this is happening, but am at a loss of how to tweak this to work for my use case.

How do I modify this to get what I am looking for/are there any other ways to tackle this issue?

Comment: You could just use `strsplit` and `grep`: `sapply(strsplit(s, '\\s+'), grep, pattern = '[[:punct:]]', value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this regex

```
/([^\s]+?[-_+][^\s]+)/g
```

I'm not familiar with **r** but tested regex is good looking! https://regex101.com/r/Sxully/1

**Note:** in implementing given regex in "" or '' , be careful about backslash and `\\` that depends on language and usage

if you want accept '_word_starting_by_underline' use this regex: (it wont be useful :) )

```
/([^\s]*?[-_+][^\s]+)/g
//    ^^^^ + changed to * to support nothing before [-_+]
```

Comment: It's logic is simple, no `\s` and exist `[-_+]` one time at least!

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern has several issues. POSIX character classes like `[:alnum:]` or `[:punct:]` must be located inside bracket expressions to be parsed as such. Another thing is that the `.*` matches any char (other than line break char in a PCRE regex), and thus will cause *overmatching* as it will return true if the lookahead pattern is found much farther in the string than you expect.

I suggest using

```
(?=[[:punct:]]*[[:alnum:]])(?=[[:alnum:]]*[[:punct:]])[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlVJy8/1)

**Details**:

- `(?=[[:punct:]]*[[:alnum:]])` - at the current position, there must be 0+ punctuation symbols followed with an alphanumeric char
- `(?=[[:alnum:]]*[[:punct:]])` - at the current position (same as above, lookaheads are zero-width assertions that do not consume text), there must be 0+ alphanumeric chars followed with a punctuation symbol
- `[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or punctuation chars.

You may add a word boundary (`\b`) on both ends if you requires an alphanumeric char at start/end of the match.