# HTML validation rules with regex

Tags: regex, html, validation

I need to validate a code format:

1. Need to be 10 characters
2. A mix of letters and numbers
3. At least 1 letter from a-f

and I write:

```
<input maxlength="200" type="text" name="code" id="code" required="required" class="form-control input-lg"  pattern="[a-fA-F0-9]{10}" title="Wrong Code" placeholder="Security Code" />
```

so my pattern is `pattern="[a-fA-F0-9]{10}"` but HOW I can add rules that at least 1 letter from a-f is required?

Comment: Required in the whole string or the beginning of the string?

Comment: at whole string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` to assert that what follows contains at least 1 occurance of `[a-fA-F]`

Updated version suggested by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

[`(?=[0-9]*[a-fA-F])[a-fA-F0-9]{10}`](https://regex101.com/r/Y6dani/1)

Explanation about the positive lookahead `(?=[0-9]*[a-fA-F])`

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]*` Match zero or more times a digit
  - `[a-fA-F]` Match a-f in lower or uppercase
- `)` Close non capturing group

```html
<form>
  <input maxlength="200" type="text" name="code" id="code" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" pattern="(?=[0-9]*[a-fA-F])[a-fA-F0-9]{10}" title="Wrong Code" placeholder="Security Code" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `(?=[0-9]*[a-fA-F])[a-fA-F0-9]{10}` will be faster.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are correct! I have updated my answer with your faster regex.

Answer (score 2):

[Regex pattern to match at least 1 number and 1 character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string)

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

Look at the regex in this thread, it should fit your needs. You need to replace your pattern with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="code" id="code" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" pattern="(?=[a-fA-F0-9]*[a-fA-F])[a-fA-F0-9]{10}" title="Wrong Code" placeholder="Security Code" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<b>
<pre>
1)Need to be 10 characters
2)A mix of letters and numbers
3)At least 1 letter from a-f
</pre></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an accepted answer, but that one is not complete.

The requirements state that there needs to be *"A mix of letters and numbers"* and *"At least 1 letter from a-f"*. That would mean that these entries below would match as well:

```
8adfl9542a
m0ammmmmmm
11111a1111
```

They do not match in the accepted answer. I created my own regex which shows that the above entries match as well:

[`(?=.*[a-fA-F]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}`](https://regex101.com/r/HRHFSs/1)

Explanation:

`(?=.*[a-fA-F]+)` Match at least one character from a-f (upper- or lowercase)

`(?=.*[0-9]+)` Match at least one number

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}` Total string must be 10 characters long and must consist of characters from a-z (upper- or lowercase) or numbers