# How to include at least once each item in a selecting group without testing?

Tags: .net, regex

I want a regex to select product references which fulfill these conditions:

- 8-character long
- starts with Q
- contains a mix of capital letters and numbers
- contains at least 1 number and 1 letter other than the initial Q
- ends with a letter or a number

For instance:

- QC1589ZH is valid ref
- Q1234567 is not a valid ref
- QUANTITY is not a valid ref

The regex will be used in a translation tool to select strings of text and block them. It will not be part of a code and thus cannot be tested or split.
The software uses .NET regexes.
I can use look-afters and look-behinds if it helps. The ref is always surrounded by spaces, line breaks, or at the begining or the end of a line.

Currently, I'm using the regex below. It works fine for valid refs but it also selects invalid refs like "Q1234567" and "QUANTITY".

```
\bQ[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

I have tried and modified several regexes suggested by others (notably here: [Regex pattern to match at least 1 number and 1 character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string)) but they are all too greedy.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Barmar's regex is just what I need here but I'm sure that I'll be using The fourth bird's method in other cases, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bQ(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Z\d]{7}\b
```

- `(?=.*[A-Z])` ensures that it contains at least one letter after the initial `Q`.
- `(?=.*\d)` ensures that it contains at least one digit.
- `[A-Z\d]{7}` requires that it contains exactly 7 letters or digits after the initial `Q`.
- `\b` matches word boundaries.

https://regex101.com/r/zEgjYk/1

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and for the detailed explanation! This works for me. I didn't realise I could use look-aheads like this.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what the answer in the question you linked to demonstrates? The main difference is that you put the initial `Q` before it.

Comment: I guess I just didn't know how to use them correctly... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your current pattern `\bQ[A-Z0-9]{7}\b` does not take a mandatory uppercase char and digit into account because the character class matches any of the listed.

For your example data, you might use:

```
\bQ(?=[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

- `\bQ` Word boundary and match Q
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z])` Assert an uppercase char
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]*[0-9])` Assert a digit
- `[A-Z0-9]{7}` Match 7 times matching any of the character class
- `\b` Word boundary

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbQ%28%3f%3d%5bA-Z0-9%5d*%5bA-Z%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5bA-Z0-9%5d*%5b0-9%5d%29%5bA-Z0-9%5d%7b7%7d%5cb&i=QC1589ZH%0d%0aQ1234567%0d%0aQUANTITY)

If there has to another uppercase char than Q following, you might [subtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#character-class-subtraction-base_group---excluded_group) Q from the character class:

```
\bQ(?=[A-Z0-9-[Q]]*[A-Z-[Q]])(?=[A-Z0-9-[Q]][0-9])[A-Z0-9-[Q]]{7}\b
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbQ%28%3f%3d%5bA-Z0-9-%5bQ%5d%5d*%5bA-Z-%5bQ%5d%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5bA-Z0-9-%5bQ%5d%5d%5b0-9%5d%29%5bA-Z0-9-%5bQ%5d%5d%7b7%7d%5cb&i=QC1589ZH%0d%0aQ1234567%0d%0aQUANTITY%0d%0aQ123456Q)

Comment: breaks on Q123456Q

Comment: hmm. question is ambiguous. "letter other than initial Q" could mean "a letter that is not Q"

Comment: @jhnc I initially misread it that way, but I'm pretty sure he means "after the initial Q".

Comment: @jhnc I have added another pattern to exclude a following `Q`

Comment: This one works well, thank you! I don't think I need the regex to be any more specific than what Barmar suggested insofar there aren't any words that mix letters and numbers (and could include other non-space characters) apart from those I want to select, but it's good to be safer, too.

Comment: @elisar It also has to do with crossing boundaries. In this example the accepted answer matches both. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbQ%28%3f%3d.*%5bA-Z%5d%29%28%3f%3d.*%5cd%29%5bA-Z%5cd%5d%7b7%7d%5cb&i=QC1589ZH%0d%0aQ1234567%0d%0aQUANTITY+QC1589ZH)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression for instance might fulfill our desired rules here:

```
\bQ(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4sw8d/1/)

Comment: This breaks on `ref is always surrounded by spaces`

Comment: Thank you, but it also select strings that don't contain letters, like Q1234567.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)^Q(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z-[q]]+[^Q]$)[a-z0-9]{7}$
```

• **`(?i)`** Case-insensitive search

• **`^Q`** String starts with `Q`

• **`(?=.*[0-9])`** Asserts string contains numbers

• **`(?=.*[a-z-[q]]+[^Q]$)`** Asserts string contains letters except `Q`and doesn't end with `Q`.

• **`[a-z0-9]{7}`** Remained 7 alphanumeric characters

• **`$`** End of the string

#### C# code:

```
var texts = new List<string>
{
    "QC1589ZH",
    "Q1234567",
    "Q12FQ457",
    "Q123F56Q",
    "QUANTITY"
};

foreach (string text in texts)
{
    var pattern = @"(?i)^Q(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z-[q]]+[^Q]$)[a-z0-9]{7}$";
    WriteLine($"Text: {text}, Is match: {Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern)}");
}

/*
    Output:
    Text: QC1589ZH, Is match: True
    Text: Q1234567, Is match: False
    Text: Q12FQ457, Is match: False
    Text: Q123F56Q, Is match: False
    Text: QUANTITY, Is match: False
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this doesn't exactly answer what I need: the ref is not alone on a line, and I never said it can't end with a Q or contain another Q. Could help someone else, though!