# Ensuring a textbox has at least one number in it using RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to ensure that a textbox has at least one number in it with validation in Visual Studio on an ASP.Net webpage.  I have gotten it so that the form must allow at least one number in it, however, it also has to have at least 1 alpha character and I would like to allow the user to have the option of only using numbers if they want.  I have tried numerous validation input statements but haven't found a way to make it work yet.  Thanks for any help you can provide, I am new to this topic and any help you can provide is appreciated.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassWord" ErrorMessage="Password Must Have a Number" ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,99})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Try this regex (ValidatorExpression): /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string

Comment: @GuilhermeMartin Thanks for the link, I tried this but it still doesn't allow what I am looking for.  Currently, I use: ValidationExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,99})$" and this works for ensuring at least 1 number is there but it also requires 1 alpha.  I would like the option for all numbers and no alphas, if that is what the user wants to input.