# Regex with numbers and alphabets mandatory, special characters optional

Tags: android, regex

In my application edittext value need at least one digit and one alphabet is mandatory, and some special characters are optional i.e ".-*", like any whare in the string.
For example ram123-*. or r_m-12.m or .--ram123 or ram123.-_.
For this I need regex. I have already tried with this one

`str_userId.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]*+[?.?_?-]")`

But not working. Here how to add special characters are optional.

Thanks, In Advance

Comment: Try `^(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])[A-Za-z._-]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*$` See https://regex101.com/r/RQZT7g/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, thanks!

Comment: Working fine, Thanks thefourthbird and WiktorStribizew

Comment: Probably a dupe of  [Regex pattern to match at least 1 number and 1 character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert at least one occurrence of a-z and after that match at least a single digit `[0-9]`.

Before and after matching the digit, you could add the `.` `_` and `-` to the character class `[A-Za-z._-]*` and repeat it 0+ times.

Note that a character class matches on of the listed characters. This notation `[?.?_?-]`, which could be written as `[?._-]` would also match a question mark instead of making the others optional

```
^(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])[A-Za-z._-]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQZT7g/1)