# Combine numbers and letters in the username in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want the pattern definition for the username to have common numbers and letters and to get an error if it enters only numbers or only letters

```
[['user'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/i']
```

Answer (score 0):

check this pattern (positive lookahead):

```
[['user'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/']
```

[found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted