# How to check if a string has at least one letter and one number

Tags: python

I am trying to build a logic where I need to write code in such a way that my string should contain

alphabet and number both. If not print sting does not contain letter else number or both

**My code:**

```
stg = 'abc123'

stg.isalnum()
```

**Output :**

```
True
```

Even if my string does not contain number then also gives me : `True`. That I don't want it

My string should contain at least one letter and number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex pattern to match at least 1 number and 1 character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string)

Comment: I think using regex for a simple text manipulation task like this is a bit overkill, @ImtinanAzhar

Comment: @ImtinanAzhar : I am expecting in python not in javascript

Comment: I guess `if any(c.isalnum() for c in stg) and any(c.isalpha() for c in stg):` does the job.

Comment: @yyy62103 you can use regex in python

Comment: @SalmanFarsi You mean `isdigit()` where you have `isalnum()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```py
import re
bool(re.match("\d+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+", stg))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

```
def hasCharNum(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString) and any(char.isalpha() for char in inputString)

hasCharNum("Python3")
```

True

Comment: What about `3Python`?

Comment: This does not work for case where the number is first

Comment: Still incorrect. The other answer works. You should probably delete your answer or edit it to say it does not work.

Comment: The regex from the comment now expects a number in the end regardless of a number being at the start already.